# Step- relation help

Tags: kinship-terminology

How does the father of my step-father relate to my daughter from her point of view?

I'm leaning toward great-grand-step-father, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you have trouble using https://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html (from the duplicate) to work it out, then feel free to describe the steps you tried and we may be able to give more help.

Comment: Usage of a website requires knowledge that said website exists. Thank you.